# Class not accesible in spite of include

Tags: c++, class, mfc

I'm new to this whole programming thing. Even though I thought I had grasped the basic idea of classes and including, I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I've made my own class called Grid which looks like this:

```
--- Grid.h ---

class Grid{

public:

Grid(HWND wnd);

public:

void paint(CDC &dc, int sqr, bool axis);            //paint the grid
void tag(CDC &dc);

private:
    int square;                                     //square size
    CRect frame;                                    //client area size
};


--- Grid.cpp ---

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Grid.h"


Grid::Grid(HWND wnd)
    {
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(wnd, &rect);                  // get client area size
    frame.left = rect.right / 2 - 387;          // fit frame to margin
    frame.right = frame.left + 774;
    frame.top = rect.bottom - 874;
    frame.bottom = rect.bottom - 100;

}

void Grid::paint(CDC &dc, int sqr, bool axis){

square = sqr;                               // paint grid
CPen penWhite;
penWhite.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 255, 255));
dc.SelectObject(&penWhite);
dc.Rectangle(frame);

dc.MoveTo(frame.left + square, frame.top);
for (int i = 1; i < 18; i++){
    dc.LineTo(frame.left + square * i, frame.bottom);
    dc.MoveTo(frame.left + square + square * i, frame.top);
}

dc.MoveTo(frame.left, frame.top + square);
for (int i = 1; i < 18; i++){
    dc.LineTo(frame.right, frame.top + square * i);
    dc.MoveTo(frame.left, frame.top + square + square * i);
}

[...]
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is add an object of this class from another class. As you might've guessed, it's an MFC app that should make use of the functionality I provide with Grid. Therefore I added

```
--- MainFrm.cpp ---

[...]

// CMainFrame construction/destruction


CMainFrame::CMainFrame()
{
    // TODO: add member initialization code here
    Grid theGrid{ GetSafeHwnd() };
}

CMainFrame::~CMainFrame()
{
}

[...]
```

in which I later call:

```
void CMainFrame::OnPaint()
{
CPaintDC dc(this);   // get device context for paint

// get current window size
CRect rect;
GetClientRect(&rect); // get current client area size

// fill background black
CBrush brushBlack;
brushBlack.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
dc.SelectObject(&brushBlack);
dc.FillRect(rect, &brushBlack);

// paint grid
theGrid.paint(dc, 43, 1);
ReleaseDC(&dc);

}  // end OnPaint()
```

... but the compiler gives me error C2065: 'theGrid' : undeclared identifier
while Intellisense is barking at theGrid.paint(dc, 43, 1);

What am I doing wrong here? I just want a Grid object created from within MainFrm that each function has access to.

Kind regards,
Michen

Comment: you also have to include the header in MainFrm.cpp

Comment: **#include "Grid.h"** at the beginning of MainFrm.cpp

Comment: I already did that but I forgot to mention.

Comment: You created the grid variable in the constructor. So it goes out of scope. It should be in the header. Then all your methods have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Grid theGrid{ GetSafeHwnd() };
```

is declared inside the constructor and thus gains a local scope only. You must declare it outside the constructor and initialize it on the constructor, like:

```
--.h file--
public class CMainFrame{
    Grid theGrid;

    [...]

--.cpp file---
CMainFrame::CMainFrame() :
    theGrid(GetSafeHwnd())
{}
```

Comment: OK, but when I Grid theGrid; it says there's no default constructor. When I add one in Grid.h like Grid(); I get the error that an ; is expected in CMainFrame::CMainFrame() theGrid(GetSafeHwnd()) right after theGrid.

Comment: I just noticed I forgot the : after the constructor and I edited it in now, is that the reason?

Comment: did that, but then ; is expected instead of :

Comment: The reason you got the "no default constructor" error is because (since I forgot the colon) the CMainFrame constructor was looking to initialize theGrid by itself. Instead of using your HWND constructor it tried to access a default constructor that doesn't exist.

Using the colon to initialize stack allocated variables before the {} is a way to assure the object you're creating, that you're initializing the variables you have declared before you start tempering with the object variables inside the {} brackets.

Comment: @Michen where does it want the ; now?

Comment: like I said, it wants it right at the : I added like you suggested. Using {} or () does not make a difference here. I just happened to pick that up while searching for an answer previously. Something about avoiding a 'most vexing parse' or whatever. Still seems like CMainFrame::CMainFrame() : theGrid(GetSafeHwnd()) is yelling for a default constructor.

Comment: @Michen I googled the most vexing parse and found "Now, in the first case, the usual workaround for this issue is to add an extra set of brackets/parenthesis around the B()"

In your case that would mean trying theGrid((GetSafeHwnd())), extra parenthesis

Comment: Making that extra () is equal to replacing all () with { } in C++11 compilers if I remember correctly. VS2013 is C++11 compliant if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Michen I'm afraid that's beyond me :( Did you include the Grid.h by the way? Like the other answer suggested?

Comment: A constructor should provide defaults in the header. Eg: Grid(HWND hWnd=NULL).

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Of course! Seems I had too much Java lately, losing my grip on source/header files :O

Comment: OK, so I did as you told me which was

- add #include "Grid.h" in MainFrm.h and MainFrm.cpp
- add Grid myGrid(HWND wnd = NULL); in MainFrm.h
- add Grid myGrid; in MainFrm.cpp
- add CMainFrame::CMainFrame() : myGrid(GetSafeHwnd()) {} in MainFrm.cpp

... and now myGrid is a nonstatic data member or base class of class "CMainFrame". Why?

Comment: Oh, and by the way: the compiler says myGrid uses undefined class 'Grid' to the statement Grid myGrid.

Answer (score 0):

**#include "Grid.h"** at the beginning of MainFrm.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Include Grid.h in you CMainFrame.h file and define theGrid as a member variable in CMainFrame

In MainFrm.h

```
#include "Grid.h"
...
class CMainFrame
{
....
    Grid theGrid;
...
};
```

I MainFrm.cpp

```
#inlcude "MainFrm.h"
...
CMainFrame::CMainFrame() : theGrid(GetSafeHwnd())
{
    // TODO: add member initialization code here
}
```

Comment: I'm following up on this but if I understand correctly it's technically the same solution like Chexxor gave below, right?

Comment: Yes, it is the same solution.